# I need to split array to sub arrays of similar values in python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

lets suppose i have this `queryset_array`:

```
queryset_array = [{"category":"a"},{"category":"a"},{"category:"b"},{"category":"b"},{"category":"c"},{"category":"c"}]
```

How can I convert this array using most efficient pythonic way into:

```
array_1 = [{"category":"a"},{"category":a"}}]
array_2 = [{"category":"b"},{"category":"b"}]
array_3 = [{"category":"c"},{"category":"c"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import groupby

queryset_array = [{"category": "b"}, {"category": "a"}, {"category": "b"}, {"category": "b"}, {"category": "c"},
                  {"category": "d"}]

def key_func(k):
    return k['category']

sorted_data = sorted(queryset_array, key=key_func)
count = 1
for key, value in groupby(sorted_data , key_func):
    print(f'array_{count}= {list(value)}')
    count += 1
```

Output

```
array_1= [{'category': 'a'}]
array_2= [{'category': 'b'}, {'category': 'b'}, {'category': 'b'}]
array_3= [{'category': 'c'}]
array_4= [{'category': 'd'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your dict is invalid
I guess you forgot a quotation mark at `{"category: "b"}`, which would look like this:

```json
[{"category":"a"},{"category":"a"},{"category":"b"},{"category":"b"},{"category":"c"}, {"category":"c"}]
```

Second, to do exactly what you're looking for, you can do this:

```py
array_1 = (queryset_array[1], queryset_array[2])
array_2 = (queryset_array[3], queryset_array[4])
array_3 = (queryset_array[5], queryset_array[6])
```

but this will only work if your `queryset_array` contains exactly 6 values.

If you want to make your code a bit more generic, you can use this:

```py
queryset_array  = [{"category":"a"},{"category":"a"},{"category":"b"},{"category":"b"},{"category":"c"}, {"category":"c"}]

queryset_array2 = []

for x in range(len(queryset_array)):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        queryset_array2.append([queryset_array[x], queryset_array[x+1]])
```

Or if the input data is not organized like that:

```py
queryset_array = [{"category": "b"},{"category": "a"},{"category": "b"},{"category": "b"},{"category": "c"},{"category": "d"}]

queryset_array2 = {}

for item in queryset_array:

    if item["category"] not in queryset_array2.keys():
        queryset_array2[item["category"]] = []

    queryset_array2[item["category"]].append(item)
```

Comment: what about if the input data look like this? 
````queryset_array = [{"category": "b"}, {"category": "a"}, {"category": "b"}, {"category": "b"}, {"category": "c"},
                  {"category": "d"}]
````
your ans will not group by this value.

Comment: @Dev I just edited my answer

Comment: Did u check your output for updated code?

Comment: `{'b': [{'category': 'b'}, {'category': 'b'}, {'category': 'b'}], 'a': [{'category': 'a'}], 'c': [{'category': 'c'}], 'd': [{'category': 'd'}]}`

Answer (score 0):

See the following another reply without using any library. I have changed the `queryset_array` to see if it works fine. I have also created a dictionary `desired_dictionary` which consists of `array_x` keys.

```
queryset_array = [{"category":"a"}, {"category":"a"},{"category":"a"}, {"category":"a"},{"category":"b"},{"category":"b"},{"category":"c"},{"category":"a"}, {"category":"b"}, {"category":"c"}, {"category":"c"},{"category":"b"},{"category":"c"}, {"category":"d"}]

def my_fnc(k):
    return k['category']

sorted_queryset_array = sorted(queryset_array, key=my_fnc)
j = 1

values_dictionary = {}
desired_dictionary = {}

for i in sorted_queryset_array: # creating values_dictionary which includes values and how many times encountered. 
    for k,v in i.items():
        val = f"value_{v}"
        if val in values_dictionary:
            j = j + 1
            values_dictionary[val] = j
        if val not in values_dictionary:
            values_dictionary[val] = 1
            j = 1

w = 1

desired_list = []

for k,v in values_dictionary.items():
    values = k.split("_")
    variable = f"array_{w}"
    for p in range(0,v):
        desired_list.append({"category": values[1]}) # This list desired_list is the desired data. 
    desired_dictionary[variable] = desired_list # Creating a dict with array_x values. 
    desired_list = []
    w = w + 1

print(desired_dictionary)

# for k,v in desired_dictionary.items():
#     print(v)
```

See the following output:

[image]